# How can I re-use the same Chrome Developer Tools Window for every tab/window?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am very used to Mozilla Firefox - Firebug. When I use Firebug it isn't linked with a particular window, it changes when you switch window or tab so the Firebug instance always show the active window, html, css, javascript etc...

As I am e Web Developer I need to test a lot in different browsers. In Google Chrome the Developer Tools seems to have linked to it's own tab/window. Sometimes this is very helpfull because it allows you to compare 2 different html-trees or css in multiple Developer Tools windows. However can I re-use the Chrome Developer Tools like it will behave as Firebug does. With just 1 instance which automatically switch between source when I switch tabs or windows? I have searched for some option but could find it in somewhere. Is this even possible with Chrome Developer Tools?

I'm using OSX Yosemite and currently Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. The best thing to do would be to file a feature request in the [issue tracker](http://crbug.com/new). I doubt this kind of functionality would be implemented.

What DevTools does is store the settings locally, so the same settings persist between all opens. Each tab you wish to debug you need to explicitly open the DevTools for; these will all share the same settings and as they are changed in one instance it will populate to the others. This keeps the context from switching on-the-fly by just changing tabs and then losing your place.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was kinda afraid this wasn't supported, more hoping that I missed some kind of setting. I filed a feature request https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507576